# Netbeans- jCalendar always asks for "Resolve Project Problems" when exported on another computer

Tags: netbeans, project, jcalendar

I'm having a problem when I exporting my Netbeans project to another computer it's because I should always resolve the project problem to that jar file.
Is there a permanent way to remove this? I'm searchin on google but I can't find good examples maybe because other people haven't experienced it? I really want to fix this. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Well, what you have to do is;   first make sure that you have the jCalendar.jar file in your project folder. Add the jCalendar.jar file  to your library and make sure that you have selected the absolute path.... and once you have done so, your project will work on any pc.